# How to remove dashes (-) in autogenerated UUID - typeorm

Tags: typeorm

I am using UUID as primary key for my entity and it works just fine. But I wish to remove those dashes.

Now ids are saved as `8e5365f4-3d42-4274-bafc-93b97bd6e3f2` **36 characters**

And what I want is `8e5365f43d424274bafc93b97bd6e3f2` **32 characters**

I dont see any option of using transformer in `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')` is there a simple way to archive this?

Comment: REPLACE(UUID(),'-','') or uuid().replace(/-/g, '')

Comment: @Treewallie how to use that in typeorm entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove the dashes when using @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid').
The UUID is either generated by the database (for example postgres) or, if not supported by the database, it is generated by a function.
See Typeorm sources (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.ts):

```
else if (column.isGenerated && column.generationStrategy === "uuid" && !this.connection.driver.isUUIDGenerationSupported() && value === undefined) {

                        const paramName = "uuid_" + column.databaseName + valueSetIndex;
                        value = RandomGenerator.uuid4();
                        this.expressionMap.nativeParameters[paramName] = value;
                        expression += this.connection.driver.createParameter(paramName, parametersCount);
                        parametersCount++;

                    // if value for this column was not provided then insert default value
                    }
```

If you really want this, you need to generate it yourself, for example:

```
import { BeforeInsert, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { v4 as uuid4 } from 'uuid';

@Entity({})
export class User {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    uuid: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    generateUuid() {
        this.uuid = uuid4().replace(/-/g, '');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`, you could use `@PrimaryColumn` with `generated: "uuid"` and specify a transformer:

```js
const removeDashes: ValueTransformer = {
  from: (str: string | null | undefined) => str != null ? str.replace(/-/g, "") : str,
  to: (str: string | null | undefined) => str != null ? str.replace(/-/g, "") : str,
};

@Entity()
export class SomeEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ type: "uuid", generated: "uuid", transformer: removeDashes })
  id: string;
}
```

Theoretically that should work with databases other than postgres (perhaps with some minor adjustments).

But if you *are* using postgres, and your column is the built-in `uuid` type, the dashes that you see in the UUID are not actually stored in the database. Instead, they're stored as a 128-bit integer, and postgres converts it to a human-readable format (with dashes) for display when needed. Postgres accepts UUID input in a variety of formats, both with and without dashes. (See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-uuid.html)

Since postgres is so flexible with input, you don't need to strip the dashes when sending a UUID to postgres if you're using the `uuid` type:

```js
const removeDashesPostgres: ValueTransformer = {
  from: (str: string | null | undefined) => str != null ? str.replace(/-/g, "") : str,
  to: (str: string | null | undefined) => str,
};
```

When typeorm transforms query results into the entity, the transformer will strip the dashes from the string representation of your UUID, so you always "see" the dash-less UUIDs in your objects. When typeorm transforms an entity into a query to save/update/etc., it passes through the string representation of the UUID to the database as-is, and postgres converts it to its own `uuid` thanks to its extreme input tolerance.

For completeness, the `id` column in the table in these postgres examples is defined as:

```sql
  id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
```